# What is the difference between load testing and discharging a LiPo?

Tags: power, batteries, lipo, testing

I would like to test max discharge rates for 1S (200 mAh) LiPo's. But I can see three ways of doing it:

1. Using a charger, discharge at highest rate and see how high the battery goes.
2. Using a resistor (0.25 Ohm) and measuring the voltage and amperage. (0.25 Ohm would generate 17.4 amps, which is a bit higher than the maximum expected amperage).
3. Using a motor and normal load, and measuring voltage and amperage.

What are the differences between these methods? Will they all expose the max discharge rate?

I would like to use method #1 since it is the simplest.

Any relevant links or references would be appreciated.

EDIT: From the comments I see that we need a distinction between burst and sustained discharge rates. For my use case, I am most interested in the burst rate.

Perhaps a good approach would be to connect it to a 0.25 Ohm resistor for 5 sec and measure the result...?

Comment: For a 200 mAh battery, 0.25 Ohms is not a discharge test. It is a short circuit. If you are planning on having this battery supply 15 A for more than a few ms, you need a new plan. Regarding discharge testing, how you do it depends on what you are trying to learn from the process. So, what are you trying to learn? Why discharge the battery at all?

Comment: Note that 17.4 / 0.2 = 87C. Is your LiPo rated to deliver 87C? I don't think so.

Comment: Haha, I thought someone would comment on 17.4A. This battery was tested at 52C: https://sites.google.com/view/rchobbylocker/1s-lipo-testing/rdq-250mah-hv-jst . It's rated at 50C burst.

Comment: You've missed most important question asked by @mkeith: what are you trying to learn? You cannot "test burst rate" using #1 or #3. You can do it using resistor (for ms, not seconds. 5s is not a "burst"), but again, what are you trying to learn? Even if the battery does not blow up on you it means exactly *nothing*, because a) it might do that next time you load it and b) it's lifespan will be already wrecked.

Comment: @Maple - I am trying to learn which batteries provide the most power using a motor at high load. (The battery might last about 3 min, so it would provide approx. 4A.)  Why do you say the battery would blow up and it's lifespan is already wrecked? It is rated at 50C. The burst rating is for 10 sec IIRC.

Comment: Bursts lasting seconds can be simulated using resistors. You can use a 1 Ohm resistor as your baseline load, then connect another resistor in parlallel for several seconds. Just use a Y connector and manually plug the load in. You may get a spark, but it should not be too bad. Bursts lasting ms need to be simulated with RC or electronic switching. A function generator connected to a FET switch is a pretty easy way to do pulse testing of any power supply, including a battery.

Comment: There is a world of difference between 52C and 87C.

Comment: There is a double electric effect creating multiple    ESR * C time constants which yield different results for I * t vs duration as well as sustained Imax vs t and gain from Temp from self-heating at the expense of rapid aging due to temp rise of the cell junction of conductor- dielectric interface . Since normal operation is from a fixed hover load current to max acceleration current this pattern of behaviour is the best test profile for you to use on one application to compare aging cells and different vendors and different batches from the same vendor.

Comment: @mkeith - OK, thanks. So I would need to choose the resistors to match the burst C rating. But I can see that is the same as discharging at a high rate for a few seconds. So I can see 2 different measurements: 1. Max Burst C rating and 2. Voltage and amperage at high load using the motor. Both of the above subject to C ratings and keeping the battery temp low.

Comment: Lithium batteries in general do not have stellar life span to begin with. It is severely affected by irreversible chemical reactions under high discharge rates, further accelerated at high temperatures (due to same high rates). Properly specified burst ratings also have stated repetition time, meaning you can't disconnect battery for a second and expect it to survive another burst right away. Finally, 4A  in your comment is not the same as 17A in your question.

Comment: If you have an electronic load, you can set that up as a constant current sink instead of a resistor. I remain totally skeptical of this whole thing, because the discharge rates you are proposing are ridiculous. Note that when you discharge at high rates, voltage will droop very noticeably. You need to anticipate this when calculating your resistor value. Some experimentation may be required before you get it right. One 12S battery pack I tested with a 0.1 Ohm load drooped from 50V to 15V under load (150 Amps). I was testing the ability of the BMS to cut out under short circuit.

Comment: The little batteries shown use a 2A connector and the battery is 4.2V when fully charged. They are used in beginners drones and RC airplanes. A 4 minutes flight uses 1A of current for the 250mAh battery shown.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot test for "max discharge rate" using any of these methods, unless you have hundreds of cells you can afford to ruin. The max discharge rate is a parameter that was determined by cell manufacturer based on specified reliability and number of charge-discharge cycles. It can be determined only by mass testing and statistical processing/analysis. Typical discharge method is to use a certified "electronic" load with constant current settings, all after manufacturer's specified charging process.

Comment: I can afford to ruin 1 of each battery ($3)! See https://sites.google.com/view/rchobbylocker/1s-lipo-testing and scroll to bottom for Testing Methods and Notes.

Comment: @BSeven, the max discharge rate is a statistical parameter. To determine it, you need to define the number of expected cycles for your battery. Therefore, technically you need to get a statistically-representative number of cells (typically about 30), and run each batch at ever increased discharge rate. You will need to take new batches with every new current for the expected number of cycles. This takes a lot of time. But if you plan to use your battery just 10-20 times, you can load it to whatever current you wish, just to watch for cell warm-up due to dissipation on internal impedance.

Comment: @BSeven, and don't do your extreme testing on room carpet or your computer desk. Use fire-retardant enclosures.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to learn which batteries provide the most power using a motor at high load. (The battery might last about 3 min, so it would provide approx. 4A.)

So, what you basically trying to test is *not* "max discharge rates", but an internal battery resistance. There are [methods to measure this](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_measure_internal_resistance) but none of them includes torturing the cell under maximum rated burst current.

Connecting the battery to the motor is an indirect but quite useful method to measure internal resistance, or rather compare performance of different cells. But once again, why do it under extreme conditions that will not happen (or will not happen often) during actual operation?

With this in mind, your method #3 is actually the best for the test goal you've specified *in your comment*, not for the one *in the title*.